# SOLR Search for similar Entries

Tags: solr

i have a table with

Forename,lastname,Street,Street_number,ZIP,House and 200 Properties

Now i want somebody to enter online has data, and i find the most similar entries using fuzzy. for example his forename could be wrong, or his last name,...

Is it correct to use SOLR?
Is it a problem if there are 80.000.000 entries?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

It is correct to use Solr for your use case, and how to use it for the use case is provided below.

Fuzzy searches uses word distance algorithm in some form, hence they are not the best in terms of performance. Having said that if you are using Solr 4+ then you should get the best deal. The performance is improved [by 100 times faster](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/03/lucenes-fuzzyquery-is-100-times-faster.html) (but with max of 2 letter changes limitation).

For use more than 2 letter distance (in your example forename can be wrong up to 2 chars) you can always go for `solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory` rather than fuzzy search to achieve better performance.

For 80MM entries, it is generally recommended to go with multiple Sharded index with or without [SolrCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud). Also it is best performance if the index size is less than total RAM size. More information on performance refer [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems)